# How to resize selection until first sheet column

Tags: excel, vba

I simply need to resize my selection from selected range to first sheet column (basically need to select everything on the left).
Let's assume the selection is `C3:E5` then I want to extend my selection to `A3:E5`. Let's assume, again, the selection is `AE12:AF34` then I want to extend my selection to `A12:AF34`.

```
If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
                SearchRange.Offset(0, -1).Select
                Range(Selection.Offset(640, Selection.End(xlToLeft)), Selection.Offset(0, 0)).Select
                                            'What to do here ^^^
End If
```

**Note:** if possible, I prefer to avoid using select, accordingly to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Let's assume the selection is `C3:E5`. What should be selected (referenced): `A3:B5`, `A3:C5`, `A3:E5`?

Comment: What do you mean by "first sheet column"? Column A:A, or first empty cell to the right on the respective row? Should `SearchRange` be a single cell, or more?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I edited the question, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select from the left column to the first (A:A), using the next approach:

```
  If Not searchRange Is Nothing Then Range(searchRange.Offset(0, -1), cells(searchRange.row, 1)).Select
```

And up to the first empty cell:

```
 If Not searchRange Is Nothing Then Range(searchRange, cells(searchRange.row, searchRange.End(xlToLeft))).Select
```

Comment: @Dovatti The above answer selects from a column to left, like in your code... In order to select the last col of `searchRange` inclusive, you should eliminate the `Offset` part. I could see now your edit and what you need... :) I edited the above answer and adapt it to return as you required in the question edit...

Comment: Yep, I've already corrected your code block according to my needs :) thanks by the way, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

### Reference From First Column

- The function references the rectangle range from the first worksheet column to the last column of a given range. Also supports non-contiguous ranges (multi-ranges).

```vb
Sub RefFromFirstColumnTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("C3:F5,AE12:AF34")
    Dim ffcrg As Range: Set ffcrg = RefFromFirstColumn(rg)
    Debug.Print ffcrg.Address(0, 0) ' Result: 'A3:F5,A12:AF34'
End Sub

Function RefFromFirstColumn(ByVal mrg As Range) As Range
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' Multi-Range
    Dim trg As Range ' Total Range
    Dim arg As Range ' Area Range
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        If trg Is Nothing Then
            Set trg = arg.Offset(, 1 - arg.Column) _
                .Resize(, arg.Columns.Count + arg.Column - 1)
        Else
            Set trg = Union(trg, arg.Offset(, 1 - arg.Column) _
                .Resize(, arg.Columns.Count + arg.Column - 1))
        End If
    Next arg
    Set RefFromFirstColumn = trg
End Function
```